# Auto-fill a new row with dynamic formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a simple Google Form for end-users to enter their email, check-out date and return date for a loaner computer. I was able to get the formula in Column H `=IF(E2=E2,MAX(TODAY()-E2,0),0)` to display the Days Overdue which checks against column E (Return Date). An apps script then runs every day and sees if the Days Overdue is greater than 0, if so, it sends a reminder to turn in email.

My issue is Column H has static cells assigned, I don't want to have to go in and copy the formula to the next cell in a newly submitted row. I have added the following to the Column H header trying to auto-populate the formula to no avail.. I've been working with a few examples but can't seem to get this to work.
`={"Days Overdue";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H="",,IF(E2=E2,MAX(TODAY()-E2,0),0)))}`

Where Column H is the "Days Overdue" row and Column E is the Return Date row. How do I dynamically change E2, to E3, E4 etc depending on the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in H2:

```
=arrayformula(if($E2:$E<>"",IF($E2:$E=$E2:$E,TODAY()-$E2:$E,0),""))
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm pretty new to Excel/Sheets formulas. So I understand the why of this working, is the `<>` feeding each cell the formula if blank?

Comment: If E is not equal to blank, execute the formula, else H is blank.